# How to get output like below?

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle DB there is one table called Employees having data like below.

```
emp_first_name    emp_surname    city
------------------------------------------
Anil              Shaw           Gurgaon
Mukesh            Jadav          Pune
```

Write a SQL query to produce output like below. The first name should have 8 characters.

```
Anil     Shaw
Gurgaon
Mukesh   Jadav
Pune
```

Comment: Do it in the display layer instead.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you having an error or an unexpected behaviour?

Comment: I came across this question in an interview and I simply don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT RPAD( emp_first-name, 8, ' ' ) || ' ' || emp_surname || CHR(10) || city
FROM   Employees;
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm :)